# Find out if column has varchar 20

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, alter

Goal:
Find out if column Firstname has `varchar(20)`. If true, alter the table etc.

Problem:
I have problem to find out if column Firstname has varchar 20 inside of (if Exists)
Everything take place in SQL server 2008 R2

table Staff
Column:

```
Firstname varchar(20)  
Lastname varchar(100)
if Exists()   // Find out if column Firstname has varchar(20)
begin 

   // Alter table and its specific column

end
```

Comment: Use the Information Schema: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx

Comment: Do you want to check if the column has that definition or if the data is that length?

Comment: Are you sure it's worth doing the check? Changing the length of a `varchar` column (what I assume you're doing) to be the same size as it already is should either be optimized out completely, or be treated the same as lengthening it - which is a metadata only operation, and quite fast.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `COLUMNS` information schema view is ideal for this.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = [table] AND COLUMN_NAME = [column]
AND DATA_TYPE = 'varchar' AND CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = 20
```

Answer (score 5):

```
IF EXISTS
    (SELECT *
    FROM    sys.columns c
    WHERE   c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('MySchema.MyTable')
    AND c.name = 'MyColumn'
    AND c.system_type_id = 167 --167 = varchar SELECT * FROM sys.types WHERE name = 'varchar'
    AND c.max_length = 20)
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE MySchema.MyTable
    ALTER COLUMN MyColumn VARCHAR(25) NULL; --or NOT NULL and/or DEFAULT ...
END
```

Comment: MySchema? What do you mean the name of the database?

Answer (score 4):

If using sys.columns - remember that the max_length column is actually the maximum size in bytes - not the actual declared size of a column.

See here for more info: [sys.columns on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106.aspx)

This works fine for char/varchar (where the size is *n* bytes), but for nchar and nvarchar the byte storage is different, where *n* is the length of the string.

nchar is 2 *n* bytes, so you will need to do `max_length/2` to get the actual declared size (1-4000)

nvarchar is also 2 *n* bytes, so you will need to do `(max_length/2)` to get the actual declared size. Although nvarchar also uses an additional 2 bytes for every column, this is not included in the sys.columns.max_length column.

**Also Remember: Any nvarchar or nchar(max) values return -1**

Example code, selects all columns for all tables and displays type details:-

```
SELECT '[' + schema_name(t.[schema_id]) + '].[' + t.name + ']' AS TableName
            , '[' + c.name + ']' AS ColumnName
            , '[' + ty.name + ']' AS DataType
            , max_length_value = CASE WHEN c.max_length > -1
                AND (ty.name = 'nvarchar' 
                OR ty.name = 'nchar') THEN c.max_length/2 
            ELSE c.max_length END
            , max_length_bytes = c.max_length
            , c.is_nullable
        FROM sys.columns AS c
            INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t ON t.object_id = c.object_id
            INNER JOIN sys.types AS ty ON ty.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
                AND ty.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
```

[nchar and nvarchar from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx) :-

**nchar**[(*n*)]
Fixed-length Unicode string data. n defines the string length and must be a value from 1 through 4,000. The storage size is two times n bytes. When the collation code page uses double-byte characters, the storage size is still n bytes. Depending on the string, the storage size of n bytes can be less than the value specified for n. The ISO synonyms for nchar are national char and national character.

**nvarchar**[(*n*|**max**)]
Variable-length Unicode string data. n defines the string length and can be a value from 1 through 4,000. max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB). The storage size, in bytes, is two times the actual length of data entered + 2 bytes. The ISO synonyms for nvarchar are national char varying and national character varying.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use something similar to this query to find if your column is varchar(20). This will select from views in the information schema and filter by column- and table-specific criteria.

```
select t.name 'Table'
    , c.name 'Column'
    , c.max_length
from sys.columns c
inner join sys.tables t on
    t.object_id = c.object_id
inner join sys.types y on
    y.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
where c.name = 'FirstName'
    and t.name = 'MyTable'
    and y.name = 'varchar'
    and c.max_length = 20
```